# I want the css file link to be saved in localstorage after the change

Tags: jquery

I want the css file link to be saved somewhere after the change but I can not get the right result, thank you check my code and tell me how to fix this problem

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="color-switcher" href="css/colors/default.css">

<div id="colors" class="topbar-menu colorlist">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><div class="color default-btn" data-path="css/colors/default.css"></div></li>
                                    <li><div class="color blue-btn" data-path="css/colors/blue.css"></div></li>
                                    <li><div class="color orang-btn" data-path="css/colors/orang.css"></div></li>
                                    <li><div class="color green-btn" data-path="css/colors/green.css"></div></li>  
                                </ul>
                            </div>

<script>
localStorage.getItem('selectedTheme');
$('.color').click(function() {      
    $(this).attr("data-path");
    $('#color-switcher').attr("href", $(this).attr("data-path"));
    localstorage.setItem("selectedTheme", $(this).attr("data-path"));
});
    
</script>
```

```js
localStorage.getItem('selectedTheme');
    $('.color').click(function() {      
        $(this).attr("data-path");
        $('#color-switcher').attr("href", $(this).attr("data-path"));
        localstorage.setItem("selectedTheme", $(this).attr("data-path"));
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" id="color-switcher" href="css/colors/default.css">

<div id="colors" class="topbar-menu colorlist">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><div class="color default-btn" data-path="css/colors/default.css"></div></li>
                                        <li><div class="color blue-btn" data-path="css/colors/blue.css"></div></li>
                                        <li><div class="color orang-btn" data-path="css/colors/orang.css"></div></li>
                                        <li><div class="color green-btn" data-path="css/colors/green.css"></div></li>  
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
```

Comment: localStorage has a capital "S". JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem was not resolved

Answer (score 0):

In browser `localStorage` api is available from `window` object. To access browser localStorage you will have to call it like `window.localStorage` . Here is updated code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="color-switcher" href="css/colors/default.css">

<div id="colors" class="topbar-menu colorlist">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><div class="color default-btn" data-path="css/colors/default.css"></div></li>
                                    <li><div class="color blue-btn" data-path="css/colors/blue.css"></div></li>
                                    <li><div class="color orang-btn" data-path="css/colors/orang.css"></div></li>
                                    <li><div class="color green-btn" data-path="css/colors/green.css"></div></li>  
                                </ul>
                            </div>

<script>
window.localStorage.getItem('selectedTheme');
$('.color').click(function() {      
    $(this).attr("data-path");
    $('#color-switcher').attr("href", $(this).attr("data-path"));
    window.localstorage.setItem("selectedTheme", $(this).attr("data-path"));
});
    
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem was not resolved

Comment: localStorage is a property of window, the "global" object which is automatically exposed to JS code running in the browser, so you don't need to write "window.localStorage"; just "localStorage" is fine. Note all the examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

I can see 3 possible issues based on this code. You may want to check each of these:

1.) Make sure the S is capitalized in `localStorage` (not `localstorage`)

2.) None of these  elements have any content in them, so they may have 0px height. (I don't know for sure without knowing what is in the .css file.) That means that there is nothing to click! Try replacing the first `<li><div>` block with this:

```html
<li><div class="color default-btn" data-path="css/colors/default.css">CLICK THIS TEXT</div></li>
```

and see if you can click on it now and get your code to work.

3.) If you are testing locally, and the URL in the address bar starts with "file:" as opposed to "http:", "https:", etc., the browser may throw a SecurityError for trying to access the Web Storage system. If this is the issue, try building the app with Node.js (or some other back-end) and using http://localhost for testing.